# Delta fleet plans - all Airbus? (and Bombardier)

Tags: airbus, boeing, boeing-787, airbus-a350

1. With Delta ordering A321neos and C-Series not 737 Max 10s, A339s, A359s instead of 789's, might Delta be on their way to an all-Airbus fleet? Or going away from Boeing?
2. Was the 737 Max vs A321neo deal **really** a "P&W over CFM" deal? Or was it just "Airbus > Boeing" etc. in disguise?
3. Would Delta **ever** actually order (and take delivery of) **any** 787's in the future? (Maybe in like 10, 20 years or so)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at current orders, yes Delta is certainly going away from Boeing. But looking at the situation today is just viewing a snapshot in time. For Delta, **right now**, these Airbus aircraft are a better value than any alternative. Things can and do change all the time. Orders are placed, cancelled, renegotiated. It is impossible to know if Delta will order any B787s in the future. It is quite possible that in 15 years you might ask this question in reverse, "Why is Delta all Boeing now??" Delta is way too big of an airline to have a single-manufacturer fleet.

If you have reason to believe of a conspiracy to support a European company rather than an American company, or suspect some other hidden motive, then you should bring it up and **give your reasons**, but you might want to go over to Skeptics.SE.

Comment: I'm not trying to be anti-Boeing or anti-Airbus. Hello!

Answer (score 1):

It does not seem that Delta is on the way to an all-Airbus fleet. As a starting point, they plan to take delivery this year of the first of at least 75 of the [Bombardier CS100](https://news.delta.com/tags/bombardier-cs100). That points to many years to come of non-Airbus aircraft for them. They also continue to receive new Boeing 737-900ER aircraft.